# Server 2012 Standard exporting a specific Role with settings via powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I have been recently trying to convert my Physical server to a Virtual Machine.  Specifically my Routing and Remote Access server that serves up L2TP connections.  I've been able to do so but the role never seems to work correctly when I boot up the new virtual server (service doesn't start, Nic's act unexpectedly).  So instead of trying to migrave from Physical to Virtual I just made a new VM and installed Server 2012 standard.  Instead of having to manually rebuild the role I'd like to try to export the Role and settings (for the RRAS role only) in powershell and create it on the new server by importing.  I've read a lot of tutorials on this but it only seems to cover exporting ALL roles and features.  In this case I really want to only export my Routing and Remote Access role with configuration.

I've used powershell to get a list of my roles, and I know how to export them all, just not the Remote Access.  Here's what I get when I run `Get-WindowsFeature | where { $_.Installed -eq $True} | select displayname, name`

```
DisplayName                                                                 Name                                                                      
-----------                                                                 ----                                                                      
File and Storage Services                                                   FileAndStorage-Services                                                   
Storage Services                                                            Storage-Services                                                          
Remote Access                                                               RemoteAccess                                                              
DirectAccess and VPN (RAS)                                                  DirectAccess-VPN                                                          
Web Server (IIS)                                                            Web-Server                                                                
Web Server                                                                  Web-WebServer                                                             
Common HTTP Features                                                        Web-Common-Http                                                           
Default Document                                                            Web-Default-Doc                                                           
Directory Browsing                                                          Web-Dir-Browsing                                                          
HTTP Errors                                                                 Web-Http-Errors                                                           
Static Content                                                              Web-Static-Content                                                        
Health and Diagnostics                                                      Web-Health                                                                
HTTP Logging                                                                Web-Http-Logging                                                          
Performance                                                                 Web-Performance                                                           
Static Content Compression                                                  Web-Stat-Compression                                                      
Security                                                                    Web-Security                                                              
Request Filtering                                                           Web-Filtering                                                             
IP and Domain Restrictions                                                  Web-IP-Security                                                           
Management Tools                                                            Web-Mgmt-Tools                                                            
IIS Management Console                                                      Web-Mgmt-Console                                                          
IIS Management Scripts and Tools                                            Web-Scripting-Tools                                                       
.NET Framework 4.5 Features                                                 NET-Framework-45-Features                                                 
.NET Framework 4.5                                                          NET-Framework-45-Core                                                     
WCF Services                                                                NET-WCF-Services45                                                        
TCP Port Sharing                                                            NET-WCF-TCP-PortSharing45                                                 
Group Policy Management                                                     GPMC                                                                      
RAS Connection Manager Administration Kit (CMAK)                            CMAK                                                                      
Remote Server Administration Tools                                          RSAT                                                                      
Role Administration Tools                                                   RSAT-Role-Tools                                                           
Remote Access Management Tools                                              RSAT-RemoteAccess                                                         
Remote Access GUI and Command-Line Tools                                    RSAT-RemoteAccess-Mgmt                                                    
Remote Access module for Windows PowerShell                                 RSAT-RemoteAccess-PowerShell                                              
SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support                                           FS-SMB1                                                                   
User Interfaces and Infrastructure                                          User-Interfaces-Infra                                                     
Graphical Management Tools and Infrastructure                               Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra                                                     
Server Graphical Shell                                                      Server-Gui-Shell                                                          
Windows Internal Database                                                   Windows-Internal-Database                                                 
Windows PowerShell                                                          PowerShellRoot                                                            
Windows PowerShell 4.0                                                      PowerShell                                                                
Windows PowerShell ISE                                                      PowerShell-ISE                                                            
WoW64 Support                                                               WoW64-Support
```

Exporting and importing the roles isn't the problem, just specifically exporting the roles I need, in this case I think it's `Remote Access`, `DirectAccess and VPN (RAS)`, and maybe some of the `RSAT` roles.

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better way to move my role and configuration?  I'm sort of a PowerShell noob and plan on trying to work as much as possible in it instead of the way I'm used to (GUI).

Comment: try this: `Get-WindowsFeature | where { ($_.Installed -eq $True) -and (($_.name -like "RemoteAccess") -or ($_.name -like "DirectAccess*") -or ($_.name -like "RSAT*"))} | select displayname, name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you followed this guide: [RRAS Migration: Migrating Routing and Remote Access Service](http://RRAS%20Migration:%20Migrating%20Routing%20and%20Remote%20Access%20Service) specifically the import and `Export-SmigServerSetting` Powershell cmds